# Function does not work correctly until after a row has been selected

Tags: ios, swift, function, uitableview, viewcontroller

I have a tableview inside a viewcontroller. I have a little function to select all rows in the tableview. When I first display the viewcontroller and hit the select all button the function does not work. However, if I firstly select a row and then press the select all button, the function works as it should and all rows are selected. I'm not sure why this is happening. The tableview's delegate and data source have been set up in the storyboard.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:myTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! myTableViewCell

    cell.accessoryType = .None

    if allJobsSelected {

        let bgColorView = UIView()
        bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 250/255, green: 182/255, blue: 17/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 250/255, green: 182/255, blue: 17/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        cell.highlighted = false

        cell.selected = true
        //  cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
        self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)

    }

    var job: Jobs!

    job = jobs[UInt(indexPath.row)] as! Jobs

    cell.reports2JobTitle.text = job.jobTitle


    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

    if let cell:myTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? myTableViewCell {

        let bgColorView = UIView()
        bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 250/255, green: 182/255, blue: 17/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 250/255, green: 182/255, blue: 17/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        cell.highlighted = false
        self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom)

    }


}

@IBAction func doSelectAll(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let totalRows = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0)
    for row in 0..<totalRows {
        tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably be a good idea to move this line:

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

to your `viewDidLoad`

You are not guaranteed that the didSelect is called immediately -- it might be that each select is turning off the previous one and then a single didSelect is being called on the last row.